# Pandas: Return count of matching values between two DataFrame variables

Tags: python, pandas

This is a simple thing but I don't think it's been covered on SO or in the Pandas documentation.

**The data**

Two DataFrames containing data about cities. The DataFrame `UK` contains a variable for UK city names. It has been grouped so there are no duplicate city names. This is a truncated example of this `city` variable, (not the full DataFrame):

```
city
Hamilton
Edinburgh
Bury
...
```

The DataFrame `US` contains a corresponding variable for US city names. It *does* have duplicate city names, but these are not actually duplicate values as there are numerous cities with the same name. Again, a truncated example:

```
city
Hamilton
Hamilton
Edinburgh
Edinburgh
Edinburgh
Bury
Bury 
...
```

(Note: The variables aren't the same length in my data.)

**The aim**

Create a new variable in the `UK` DataFrame which is an integer count for each time a city name in the `US` city variable matches a city name in the `UK` city variable.

Below shows an example of the output I'm aiming for. Say for one UK city called Hamilton there are 2 cities called Hamilton in the US. For one UK city called Edinburgh there are 3 matches in the US. And 2 matches for Bury.

```
city       count
Hamilton       2
Edinburgh      3
Bury           2
```

**Where I'm stuck**

If I do this...

```
uk['count'] = uk['city'].isin(us['city']).astype(int)
```

the new variable is a binary 1 or 0 indicating that there is a match, which is halfway there. However I'm struggling with the Pandas syntax to return the *count* of matches. I've tried appending `value_counts` and variations of unique but these didn't work. Maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to count the number of occurrences for each city in `US['city']`, and then use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) to apply those counts to corresponding values in `UK['city']`:

```
In [40]: US['city'].value_counts()
Out[40]: 
Edinburgh    3
Bury         2
Hamilton     2
Name: city, dtype: int64

In [41]: UK['count'] = UK['city'].map(US['city'].value_counts())

In [42]: UK
Out[42]: 
        city  count
0   Hamilton      2
1  Edinburgh      3
2       Bury      2
```

If there is a city in `UK['city']` which is not in `US['city']` then the above will assign a `NaN` value to the count column for that city.